# Records with Publication date greater than today and less than the expiration date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want all records that are within the allowed dates.

```
SELECT
  page_id, page_published_date, page_expired 
FROM 
  pages
WHERE
  ([page_published_date] &lt;= getdate() OR [page_published_date] is null)
  AND
  ([csp_expired] &lt;= getdate() OR [page_expired] is null)
```

Mind that dates can contain null values.

Example table:

```
page_id, page_published_date, page_expired
1        2012-10-05           null
2        null                 2012-10-01
3        2012-08-01           2012-11-30
```

In this case the correct record would be 3.

Comment: You have _two_ `<=` there... did you mean `page_published_date >= getdate()`?

Comment: Any page not be shown before published_date, is the date to init vizualization!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer, based on choosing #3 as the only result

```
SELECT
  page_id, page_published_date, page_expired 
FROM 
  pages
WHERE
  -- Publication date BEFORE today (current time)
  ([page_published_date] <= getdate() OR [page_published_date] is null)
  AND
  -- and page has not expired
  (datediff(d,0,getdate()) < [page_expired] OR [page_expired] is null)
```

---

Direct translation from subject line

```
SELECT
  page_id, page_published_date, page_expired 
FROM 
  pages
WHERE
  -- Publication date greater than today
  ([page_published_date] > DateDiff(D,0,getdate()) OR [page_published_date] is null)
  AND
  -- and [Publication date?] less than the expiration date
  ([page_published_date] < [page_expired] OR [page_expired] is null)
```

Notes:

1. `DateDiff(D,0,getdate())` gives you "today", i.e. without the time portion
2. I have a feeling you don't want to compare [page_expired] against today, since today pre-dates the [page_published_date] given the first condition
3. Use my pattern of translation to plug in any changes as required, if my interpretation is wrong

Comment: Excuse my English! But I thought the intended result with the following condition.

'where 
  ([page_published_date] <= DateDiff(D,0,getdate()) OR [page_published_date] is null)
  AND
  (datediff(d,0,getdate()) <= [page_expired] OR [page_expired] is null)'

Any page not be shown before published_date, is the date to init vizualization!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  page_id, page_published_date, page_expired 
FROM pages
WHERE
(
    [page_published_date] >= getdate()
    OR [page_published_date] is null
)
AND (
    [page_expired] <= getdate()
    OR [page_expired] is null
)
```